# wordpress or codeigniter

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter

I know my question isn't about programming problem, I just need a suggestion to get started on right direction but I'm guessing this non-question post is going to be close :( there should be two types of post, "ask question" and "ask suggestion" :D

I'm a beginner in PHP and currently getting my hands dirty on PHP OOP, made a little framework.

I'm planning to learn codeigniter and wordpress, Kindly suggest me which thing should I start first with? 
can I do full projects with wordpress like college/university CMS? Shopping cart? etc custom forms with dynamic fields/data? 
Can I use codeigniter scripts in wordpress custom page?

Comment: Worpress is CMS but codeigniter is framework. They are completely different things. If you new at php programming try simple scripts to learn OOP. Than you can start to codeigniter

Comment: I know the difference between these two and I've made custom cms projects with php oop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off I don't know codeigniter.
But of course it is possible to use codeigniter scripts in your wordpress plugins and theme's.
This plugin should do that: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-code-igniter/

Do beware that Wordpress had a lot of build in functions for developers.
Try not to duplicate functions. Like the database connection use [wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) and others.

Read the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/), start with building your own [theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) before moving into you own [plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin)
And if you start building then codeignitor should be usefull, everything(like 95%) you need to do in a theme should be possible with build in wordpress functions.

Comment: cool, I'd created some basic custom themes in wordpress, but i'm still confuse about wordpress, can I make CMS in wp as I can make in some framewok/php? googling it more.

Comment: Wordpress is not a framework, Wordpress is a cms. A lot of functions like adding pages building menu's are all in WP, you don't need to program any of that, and it's super userfriendly.

Comment: WP is great for starters, you can make WP to do a huge variety of things. I'm experiencing WP and I now can say that too "WP is not just a CMS". :) anyways after WP i'll go for YII.

Comment: a PHP framework, like cakePHP, CodeIgniter. I didn't try any of them yet.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you learn codeigniter instead. here is a tutorial series that will get you going. [Codeigniter from Scratch](http://net.tutsplus.com/sessions/codeigniter-from-scratch/)

Comment: yeah, I'm gopna learn CI but can you explain why you have given prefernce to CI?

Comment: because you will have more to learn in codeigniter, you would have to make stuff, whereas in wordpress you can get a plugin for anything. and also wordpress is cms whereas codeigniter is a framework. you would have more flexibility with codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest to starts with ci, as in ci you can builtup customization easily. While wp you have lots of limitation for customize project, and querying. WP is good for cms only, and in CI you are free to built costumize as well as cms project also.